# Is there a coordinate geometry calculator

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, calculator

I am looking for a calculator where I can input the coordinates of some points, connect some points, and find the intersection of lines (as coordinates). Does something like this exist?

Ideally, it would also have circles, perpendicular lines, or be able to solve for the coordinate of some points given enough conditions.

Comment: Geogebra has something like this. I never really tried it before however.

Comment: Yes, geogebra has such tools. It is free to download or to use online,